# Spring mvc (thymeleaf+hibernate) Как создать сущность со связью многие ко многим?

Tags: spring, hibernate, mvc, jpa, thymeleaf

недавно решил взяться за изучения Spring MVC. Есть 2 сущности, туры(туристические поездки) и водители, эти сущности связанны отношением многие ко многим. Соответственно класс Tour содержит поле Set drivers. Есть html страничка, где находятся неободимые поля для ввода и dropdown список из существующих водителей. Моя проблема в том что я не знаю как создать тур с водителями выбранными пользователем. 
Сущности выглядят след. образом. Туры:

```
    @Indexed
    @Entity(name = "tours")
    @JsonRootName(value = "tour")
    public class Tour {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "tour_id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        @Column
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
        private Calendar startDate;
        @Column
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
        private Calendar endDate;
        @Column
        private int days;
        @Column
        private String tittle;
        @Column
        private String description;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinTable(name="tours_drivers", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tour_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="driver_id")})
        private Set<Driver> drivers = new HashSet<>();

        public Tour() {
            if(startDate != null && endDate != null)
                days = endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        }

        public void addDriver(Optional<Driver> driver){
            drivers.add(driver.get());
        }

        public void addDriver(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName){
            var driver = new Driver();
            driver.setFirstName(firstName);
            driver.setMiddleName(middleName);
            driver.setLastName(lastName);
            drivers.add(driver);
        }
// getters and setters
```

Водители:

```
@Indexed
@Entity(name = "drivers")
@JsonRootName(value = "driver")
public class Driver implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "driver_id")
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String middleName;

//    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    private Set<Tour> tours = new HashSet<>();

    public Driver() {
    }
// getters and setters
```

Создать сущность водителся не составило труда, т.к. в нем только простые типы данных, есть сервис который использует CrudRepository для создания записи в БД. Метод в контролере:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDriverAction(@ModelAttribute("driver") Driver driver, Model model) {
        driverService.createDriver(driver);
        model.addAttribute("driver", driver);
        return "redirect:/drivers/add";
    }
```

А вот с турами посложнее.

Имеется метод в контроллере, который возвращает представление и список существующих водителей. Выглядит он так:

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView getAddTourView(Model model) {
        var map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put("tourForm", new Tour());
        map.put("drivers", driverService.getDriversList());

        return new ModelAndView("addTourPage.html", map);
    }
```

Представление:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/tours/save}" th:object="${tourForm}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Tittle:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{tittle}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Start date:</td>
                <td><input id = "startDate" type="datetime-local" th:field="*{startDate}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End date:</td>
                <td><input id = "endDate" type="datetime-local" th:field="*{endDate}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="id" type="java.lang.Long"*/-->
                    <select th:field="*{id}" multiple="true">
                        <!--/*@thymesVar id="drivers" type="java.util.List<stanislav.tun.novinomad.picasso.persistance.pojos.Driver>"*/-->
                        <option th:each="d : ${drivers}" th:value="${d.id}" th:text="${d.id+' '+d.fullName}">

                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit">Create</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

[image: add tour screen]

Как видно выпадающий список заполнется сам из контроллера, но как теперь создать тур? Как должен выглядеть метод в контроллере? Что там вообще писать? 
Можно сделать запись из контроллера в join таблицу написав что-то типа:

```
    @RequestMapping("/test")
        public void createtour(){
            var tour = new Tour();
            tour.setTittle("Awesome tour");
            var driver = new Driver("John", "Smith");
            driverService.createDriver(driver);
// след. строка добавляет водителя в Set 
            tour.addDriver(Optional.of(driver));
// сохраняем в базу
            tourService.createTour(tour);
        }
```

Но как сделать что-то подобное через представление если я использую thymeleaf?

Я проовал искать ответы. Был вариант передавать ID водителся, потом вытаскивать его из базы методом findByID, но даже так я не знаю как передать ID водителся из представления в контроллер. Но этот подход не позволит создать тур сразу с несколькими водителями, а только по одному добавлять. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Уже 2 недели не могу найти способ)

P.S. для тех кто будет писать что вопрос с похожей темой уже есть, то вот знайте, я бы не создавали эту тему опять, если бы ответы на уже созданные темы помогли, я искал обучающие видео, искал на stackoverflow. Также проблема в том, что может быть я не до конца понимаю сути spring mvc и thymeleaf, но я только начал изучать.

Comment: Нашел способ как создать тур с водителем, добавил в метод контроллера параметр @RequestParam(required = false, name = "driverId") Long driverId. Также в представлении изменил select option:  <select th:name="driverId">
                        <!--/*@thymesVar id="drivers" type="java.util.List<stanislav.tun.novinomad.picasso.persistance.pojos.Driver>"*/-->
                        <option th:each="d : ${drivers}" th:value="${d.driverId}" th:text="${d.driverId+' '+d.fullName}"/>
                    </select> Дальше просто: var driver=driverService.getDriver(driverId);tour.addDriver(driver);

Comment: По прежнему остается вопрос как создать тур сразу с несколькими водителями. Возможно сделать что-то типа: @RequestParam(required = false, name = "driverId") Long[] driverIds. И в представлении, в select option, добавить аттрибут multiple="multiple", далее в контролере пробегаться циклом и добавлять водителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ. Сначала мне удалось создать тур с 1 водителем. Далее как и предпологал вместо 1 параметра в методе контроллера передавать массив, однако когда передавал массив Long[] то туры не создавались по непонятной мне причине, просто не попал в блок цикла. Запись в базе создавалась только в таблице для туров, но в join таблицу запись так и не попала. Дебажить не пробовал, просто попробовал заменить массив на List и в представлении добавил аттрибут multiple все заработало. Действительно магия Spring. В итоге метод в контроллере приобрел след. вид (не обращайте внимания на принты):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addTourAction(@ModelAttribute("tourForm") @Valid Tour tour,
                                @RequestParam(required = false, name = "driverId") List<Long> driverId,
                                    Model model) {
            System.out.println("DRIVERS IDS "+driverId.size());


        var start = tour.getStartDate();
        var end = tour.getEndDate();

        if (start != null && end != null)
            tour.setDays(end.getDayOfYear() - start.getDayOfYear());

        if(driverId.size() > 0){
            System.out.println("DriverS more than 1");
            for(Long id : driverId){
                System.out.println("Driver id in addTourAction param = "+ id);
                var driver = driverService.getDriver(id);
                System.out.println("DRIVER = "+driver.toString());
                tour.addDriver(driver);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("DRIVER ID IS EMPTY!");
        }

        tourService.createTour(tour);
        model.addAttribute("tour", tour);
        return "redirect:/tours/add";
    }
```

в представлении добавил небольшие изменения, а именно в тэг select добавил аттрибут th:name="***driverId***" и multiple="multiple". Здесь важна связка с контроллером, значение аттрибута th:name должно совпадать с именем параметра в контроллера @RequestParam(required = false, name = "***driverId***") List ***driverId*** форма выглядит в итоге так:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/tours/save}" th:object="${tourForm}" method="post">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td>Tittle:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{tittle}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start date:</td>
            <td><input id="startDate" type="datetime-local" th:field="*{startDate}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>End date:</td>
            <td><input id="endDate" type="datetime-local" th:field="*{endDate}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Attach a driver</td>
            <td>
                <select th:name="driverId" multiple="multiple">
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="drivers" type="java.util.List<stanislav.tun.novinomad.picasso.persistance.pojos.Driver>"*/-->
                    <option th:each="d : ${drivers}" th:value="${d.driverId}"
                            th:text="${d.driverId+' '+d.fullName}">
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit">Create</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
</form>
```

К сожалению на момент ответа я не смог найти источник который навел меня на эту мысль, однако я дополню ответ, как только проведу поиск по истории браузера)) 
В этом создании обьекта Tour и была суть проблемы, как собственно и вопроса, но к сожалению мне не хватало опыта правильно подобрать слова для его описания. Так или иначе проблема решена.

P.S. Может кто-то знает иной способ решения этой проблемы? Какая-нибудь другая реализация, координально другая логика возможно. Добавьте пожалуйста это в ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Пример создания связи многие ко многим https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

В вашем варианте будет так:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "tours")
  public class Tour{ 
  // ...

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name = "tours_drivers", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tour_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id") }
  )
  private List<Driver> drivers;

  // standard constructor/getters/setters
  }
```

, где `tours_drivers` - таблица связей туров с водителями.

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "drivers")
  public class Driver{    
    // ...  

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "drivers")
    private List<Tour> tours;

    // standard constructors/getters/setters   
  }
```

Comment: Z.John, Вы неверно поняли вопрос, у меня нет проблем с моделью, т.е. я могу сделать запись в бд в join таблице tours_drivers вручную, написав что то вроде 
@RequestMapping("/test")
    public void createtour(){
        var tour = new Tour();
        tour.setTittle("Uahahaha");
        var driver = new Driver("Миша", "Пупкин");
        driverService.createDriver(driver);
        tour.addDriver(Optional.of(driver));
        tourService.createTour(tour);
    } проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать используя Thymeleaf. Возможно мой вопрос не совсем корректный

Comment: в описании я и так сказал что у меня уже есть коллекция водителей в турах:" Соответственно класс Tour содержит поле Set drivers". А вопрос был: как создать тур? Запись в базе в join таблице по нажатию на кнопку в представлении, при чем водителей можно выбрать несколько. Я пробовал (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836329/how-to-submit-a-manytomany-attribute-in-spring-mvc) данный вариант, но не подходит, т.к. нет возможности выбрать сразу несколько. В контроллер переается только 1 ID, да и в ответе мне не понятно как именно передается ID сущности в контроллер